# No such file, Storing file into the local storage is not working on production

Tags: laravel, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a laravel application deployed on Elasticbeanstalk, I'm working on a feature where I need to get a zip file from s3 bucket, store it into the local storage in order to be able to use laravel-zip to remove a pdf file from that zip. 
the code is working locally, but I'm receiving 'No Such file error' after testing on production:

```
// get the file from s3 and store it into local storage
$contents  = Storage::disk('s3')->get($file_name);
$zip_local_name =  'my_file.zip';
Storage::disk('local')->put($zip_local_name, $contents);

// use laravel-zip to remove the unwanted pdf file from the result
$manager = new ZipManager();
$file_path = storage_path('app').'\\'.$zip_local_name; // register existing zips
$manager->addZip(Zip::open($file_path));
$zip = $manager->getZip(0);
$zip->delete($data["Iso_Bus"]["field_name"].'.pdf');
$zip->close();
```

I made sure that the file exists on s3, so I think my main problem is that the file is not stored in the local storage.
Any help is appreciated

*Edit* filesystems configrations:

```
'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',                              
            'key' => '***',
            'secret' => '***',
            'region' => '***',
            'bucket' => '****',
            'url' => '****',
        ],

    ],
```

Comment: Are you sure you have write permissions and could you add your filesystems.php config?

Comment: give me a mnt please

Comment: @JasperHelmich could you please explain what write permissions do I need?

Comment: @FurqanS.Mahmoud on which line you're getting this error?

Comment: @HA $manager->addZip(Zip::open($file_path));

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's a permissions issue now, I never set any permissions to the storage folder before in  .ebextensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting full path for the file wrongly, try this one instead:

```php
$file_path = Storage::disk('local')->path($zip_local_name);
```

Note: It's better to check if the `Storage::put` was successful before continue:

```php
// get the file from s3 and store it into local storage
$contents  = Storage::disk('s3')->get($file_name);
$zip_local_name =  'my_file.zip';

if (Storage::disk('local')->put($zip_local_name, $contents)) {
    // `Storage::put` returns `true` on success, `false` on failure.
    // use laravel-zip to remove the unwanted pdf file from the result
    $manager = new ZipManager();
    $file_path = $file_path = Storage::disk('local')->path($zip_local_name);
    $manager->addZip(Zip::open($file_path));
    $zip = $manager->getZip(0);
    $zip->delete($data["Iso_Bus"]["field_name"].'.pdf');
    $zip->close();
}
```